# ajax call in ascx File

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ascx file, in which I am making an ajax call to a function located in another file(aspx code behind file). But its returning complete aspx page in Result, I am returning just string in my function,Below is my code
This is in my ascx file

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyFile.aspx/GetData", //url to point your webmethod          
            success: function (Result) {
                alert('success');
                $("#txtlicense").val(Result);
            },
            error: function () { alert('error'); }
        });
```

and this is in MyFile.aspx.cs

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static string GetData()
        {
//Getting data from DB and returning 

        }
```

I also tried placing this method in my ascx.cs file but its giving error

```
This type of page is not served
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

See the following working example

// Code behind method declared static

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSquare(String value)
{
    return value;
}
```

your button whose click this has to be done

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Chnageurl" onclick="ajaxcall()" />
```

script for this

```
<script type="text/jscript">

function ajaxcall(e) {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetSquare",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ value: "Vinay" }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (value) {
            alert(value.d);
        },
       error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
     });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks alot, 2nd time I was missing this contentType :)